# How to append two stringBuilders?

Tags: c#, stringbuilder

Is there a way to append two string builders? 
And if so - does it perform better than appending a string to a StringBuilder ?

Comment: stringBuilder1.Append(stringBuilder2.ToString()); http://www.dotnetperls.com/stringbuilder-1

Comment: I think this Question is not named as it should be !

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just like that....

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(sb1.ToString());
```

Comment: That's appending a string to a sb. I thought to append to sb to avoid sealing sb to string

Answer (score 42):

I know this is three years later, but the .NET 4 `StringBuilder` behaves differently anyway.

Nevertheless, it does still come back to "what do you want to do?" Are you looking for simply the most performant way of appending two `StringBuilders` and continuing on with just the latter result? Or are you expecting to continue working with the existing buffered value of the appended `StringBuilder`?

For the former, and always in .NET 4,

```
frontStringBuilder.Append(backStringBuilder);
```

is best.

For the latter scenario in .NET 2/3.5,

```
frontStringBuilder.Append(backStringBuilder.ToString(0, backStringBuilder.Length));
```

is best (and won't hurt performance in .NET 4).

Comment: Very clear answer. I thought it could be worth adding that .AppendLine() does NOT provide the same flexibility, in case anyone wonders.

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato I'm not sure what you mean: `.AppendLine` is implemented as `.Append(string)` followed by `.Append(NewLine)` for both .NET 2.0/3.5 and 4, which means both of the scenarios above are the same.

Comment: Sorry @MarkHurd I wasn't clear enough: what I meant is, although `.ApppendLine` is really implemented as you described, it only accepts `String` as a parameter in any .NET versions. So, even in .NET 4, you can't just do a `.AppendLine( backStringBuilder )` - what I meant with "lacking flexibility". Not a problem, just a note - it's only an extra method call, anyway.

Comment: @CharlesRobertoCanato Actually, you're highlighting a recent change to the code: I removed the explicit `.ToString` because, as Nigrimmist mentions in his answer, `.ToString` is currently implied and, in the future, maybe there will be an overload that _does_ accept a `StringBuilder` directly.

Comment: under the hood `frontStringBuilder.Append(backStringBuilder)` calls  `backStringBuilder.toString()` inside. so it's basically  `frontStringBuilder.Append(backStringBuilder.ToString())` .

Comment: @rovsen Yes, that's what I had until Nigrimmist pointed out that it would be better for future possibilities of a `StringBuilder` direct overload were to become available.

Answer (score 19):

This will do it without allocations

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("aaaa");    
StringBuilder second = new StringBuilder("bbbbb");
sb.EnsureCapacity(sb.Length + second.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < second.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(second[i]);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the indexer property in `StringBuilder` is non-trivial and actually iterates over each "chunk" inside the StringBuilder for **every** access, making this somewhat expensive to use in a loop. For my implementation I used a reusable `Char[]` buffer if the `StringBuilder` is more than ~4,000 characters long.

Answer (score 14):

You don't need to call `.ToString()`. You should simply append one to another. That's all. It will be better against direct `.ToString()` call for next reason :

1) StringBuilder does not have constructor with `StringBuilder` as a param, string, int/string etc. `StringBuilder` overriding `.ToString()` and as a result :

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("1");
sb1.Append(new StringBuilder("2"));
Console.WriteLine(sb1);
```

that code will call overrided version of `.ToString()` automatically. Output will be `"12"`;

2)If `StringBuilder` will be added as incoming param to `StringBuilder` constructor's in next framework versions, your code will be clear and ready for correct appending without any refactoring.

Have a good day!

Comment: Great suggestion and clean understandible coding

Answer (score 6):

If the StringBuilder is large, then this will minimize string-allocations (especially if you can provide a reusable char-buffer):

```
    public static void CopyTo(this StringBuilder source, StringBuilder dest)
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[Math.Min(source.Length, 1024)];
        CopyTo(source, dest, buffer);
    }

    public static void CopyTo(this StringBuilder source, StringBuilder dest, char[] buffer)
    {
        dest.EnsureCapacity(dest.Length + source.Length);
        for (int i = 0; i < source.Length; i += buffer.Length)
        {
            int charCount = Math.Min(source.Length - i, buffer.Length);
            source.CopyTo(i, buffer, 0, charCount);
            dest.Append(buffer, 0, charCount);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply as that:

```
firstStringBuilder.Append(secondStringBuilder.ToString());
```